# HTML button looks different in gmail

Tags: html

The button I made looks different in gmail.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOSqg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErdC2.png)

Answer (score 0):

if its just html, you need to add some CSS, like so:

```
<style>
body {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```